# What is the best way to take data from state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

What is the best way to take data from state? Dispatching the data once in index.js and then simply filtering the array in each component and displaying the necessary data (for example, for the category Dogs, filter by the attribute "Dogs", for cats - cats, etc.). Or is it better for each component where you need to do your own useEffect and dispatch there, and for each make a separate call to the server?

Comment: There's no generic answer to this; it depends on requirements, preferences, architecture, etc.

Comment: The best way to take data from the State is to declassify the information and take it home with you.   But seriously, Dave's answer is kind of the best one, due to the broadness of the scope.

Comment: You're really asking about the best way to populate the state, not access it. While it depends on a lot of factors, redux lends itself well for a cache-first approach. I believe parts of redux-toolkit also embrace this (RTK Query). In a nutshell, you always display data from cache (app feels very snappy) but also fetch for updates. It is vastly superior to fetching data only on-demand in my opinion. There is a bit of complexity overhead however.